# Format riemann emails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, clojure, riemann

I use riemann ruby client for email alerting. And my emails look like this:

```
#riemann.codec.Event{:host "foo", :service "bar", :state "critical", :description "{\"exception\":\"some error\",\"datetime\":\"20210104061928\"..."}
```

When the contents of the email are large (when I get exception backtrace), it becomes very hard to understand the data.

Is there a way to receive this data in a JSON format so that it can be copy-pasted into a code editor and formatted easily?

I cant find any docs on email formating in these repos:

https://github.com/riemann/riemann

https://github.com/riemann/riemann-ruby-client

Comment: I don't know Riemann but what I understand of it is that the Ruby-client only sends events to the Riemann server, and that would be the server that sends the emails to you, not the other way around. My point is that there may be some email formatting options in the server configuration part

Comment: From that portion you have pasted, the `:description` looks like JSON already. Paste that in your editor as EDN (or clojure code), then copy the string from `:description` as JSON.

Comment: can you edit your question to attach a copy of some example code you're using to send via Riemann?

Comment: I came here for a question about integration! ;)